# debugging distcc: no job seems to run on slave

Tags: c++, linux, distcc

First, my ultimate goal is to cross compile **OpenCV** for `arm` so I have tried 2 approaches, but no success so far.

This question is related to using `distcc` for compiling, using the `target` to run the `make` command but taking advantage of a beefy server to speed things up.

Basically, the `target` doesn't seem to be sending jobs to the `slave` server.

I installed `distcc` on both machines (`apt-get install distcc`)

As I understand it, the daemon only needs to run on the slave.
I set up hosts in `/etc/distcc/hosts`: In that file I have the IPs of both the `target` at `192.168.10.45` and `slave` at `192.168.10.34`

I run the daemon with

`distccd --daemon --allow 192.168.10.45`

to allow the `target`

with `ps aux | grep distcc`

I can see the 32 instances of `distccd` running.

If I use

`netstat -pant | grep distcc`

I see the daemon listening

Now, if I tail the log file at `/var/log/distccd.log`, there is nothing there, and nothing happening

When I run a job on the `target` with

`make -j33 CC=distcc`

it seems to run fine, but I see nothing happening on the `slave`

`ufw` is disabled, the 2 machines ping and can talk to each other via ssh.

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: I had to run `sudo update-distcc-symlinks`

Which I found by checking the log:

    DISTCCD_OPTS="${DISTCCD_OPTS} --log-file /var/log/distccd.log" 

In my case, my log said:

    (dcc_warn_masquerade_whitelist) CRITICAL! /usr/local/lib/distcc not found. You must see up masquerade (see distcc(1)) to list whitelisted compilers or pass --enable-tcp-insecure. To set up masquerade automatically run update-distcc-symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

1. You must define the list of compilation hosts (through the `/etc/distcc/hosts` file or through the `DISTCC_HOSTS` environment variable) on the master (`target`) machine. Check the host list by running on the master `distcc --show-hosts`.
2. Specify `distcc` as a compiler for C++ as well:

   ```
   make -j33 CC=distcc CXX=distcc
   ```

Comment: thanks, i did all that, but no activity on the host; i tried CC, CXX, G++,GXX. I added bth host and target in the hosts file. distcc --show-hosts shows the hosts on both side.

Comment: target is a ARM board with 4CPU. slave is a dual xeon 32 cores. I tried running on target as well with both target and slave as hosts, but still no change. nothing in the logs. I tried running with --verbose flag, and --log-stderr --no-detach so i can see what's happening but there is no activity after initiating the daemon children.

Comment: according to this: https://debian-administration.org/article/112/Speed_up_compiling_software_with_distcc i should see connections from target on the slave, but nothing.

Comment: Try building without using the target as a compilation host (assuming your shell is bash): `DISTCC_HOSTS=192.168.10.34 make -j33 CC=distcc CXX=distcc`

Comment: I think i'm giving up on this for now... thanks for your help. I actually figured how to cross-compile now and got opencv compiled in 3min instead of the 7-8h on the board!

Comment: i'll get back to this eventually.

Comment: My guess is that OpenCV's CMake setup uses gcc directly, so that `CC=distcc` passed to make has not effect

Comment: You can check this conjecture by running `make CC=qwerty`

Answer (score 0):

Did you run:

```
sudo update-distcc-symlinks
```

The official installation documentation currently omits this step. I had the same symptoms and had some trouble finding the log, but eventually saw that I had to specify logging in an environment variable:

```
DISTCCD_OPTS="${DISTCCD_OPTS} --log-file /dev/shm/distccd.log"
```

Which said:

```
(dcc_warn_masquerade_whitelist) CRITICAL! /usr/local/lib/distcc not found. You must see up masquerade (see distcc(1)) to list whitelisted compilers or pass --enable-tcp-insecure. To set up masquerade automatically run update-distcc-symlinks.
```